# Opencart Affiliate member Cookies Null

Tags: php, session, cookies, opencart2.x

I am new to open cart, I have issues on retrieve cookie data. I set my cookies on index page and cookies shows in browser and show on index page also works fine but when I retrieve my cookies on affiliated controller cookies show `null` data. What will be the issue?

Comment: Please post your relevant code so that we can help you :)

Comment: i set my cookies index.php                                                                                                                    if (isset($request->get['tracking'])) {
 setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24, '/'); print_r($_COOKIE,ture) this is olk                            }                                    now i go affliate modal and write this code to get cookies $this->request->cookie['tracking'] but it shows null